# patrón matriz cuadrada por niveles imshow

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

Estoy intentando crear está matriz a nivel de código, donde cada uno de los colores es 0 o 1.
Se supone que solo introduciendo el numero de filas o columnas se debería de generar esta matriz:

```
1111111
1000001
1011101
1010101
1011101
1000001
1111111
```

El problema es que no acabo de entender la lógica de esto... [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea mínima de como enfocar este problema? Tengo el codigo de un tablero de ajedrez desde el cual se supone deberia ser facil hacer este patron.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Creamos una matriz de zeros 5x5
Z = np.zeros((5,5),dtype=int)
# Comenzando en la fila 1 y cada 2, ponemos 1 cada 2 columnas
Z[1::2,::2] = 1
# Comenzando en columna 1 y cada 2, ponemos 1 cada 2 filas
Z[::2,1::2] = 1
print(Z)
plt.imshow(Z)
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Tal vez en un bucle, alternando entre 0 y 1?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 20
Z = np.zeros((N, N), dtype=int)
for k in range(1, (N + 1) // 2):
    Z[k:-k, k:-k] = k % 2
plt.imshow(Z)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image: cuadrados en un bucle]